# How does data looks like when stored in a key-value and graph nosql databases

Tags: redis, nosql, graph-databases, key-value-store

I'm currently studying data engineering and I'm figuring out how does data looks like when stored in different data stores, here's what I've gathered so far. I couldn't find good explanation for graph and key value data stores.

```
Given the table: Bonuses
    ID         Last    First   Bonus
    1          Doe     John    8000
    2          Smith   Jane    4000
    3          Beck    Sam     1000

row oriented database(e.g. postgresql):
    1,Doe,John,8000;2,Smith,Jane,4000;3,Beck,Sam,1000;

column oriented database(e.g. mariadb):
    1,2,3;Doe,Smith,Beck;John,Jane,Sam;8000,4000,1000;

column family database(e.g. cassandra):
    "Bonuses" : {
        row1 : { "ID":1, "Last":"Doe", "First":"John", "Bonus":8000},
        row2 : { "ID":2, "Last":"Smith", "First":"Jane", "Bonus":4000},
        row3 : { "ID":3, "Last":"Beck", "First":"Sam", "Bonus":1000}
    }

document based database (e.g. mongodb):
    document1  
        { 
            "ID": 1,
            "Last": "Doe",
            "First": "John",
            "Bonus": 8000
        }
    document2
        {
            "ID": 2,
            "Last": "Smith",
            "First": "Jane",
            "Bonus": 4000
        } 
    document3
        {
            "ID": 3,
            "Last": "Beck",
            "First": "Sam",
            "Bonus": 1000
        }

graph database(e.g. neo4j): ???

key-value database(e.g. redis: ???
```

Comment: Notice you can use Redis for both Key value and for Grpah database (with RedisGraph module). You can use RedisInsight to visualize it.

Comment: Not sure what you mean my "stored". The fact that a particular product is a graph database is more a statement of what features it presents at the user/API layer and not the storage layer. InfiniteGraph is an object/graph database and uses a pure binary representation at the storage layer. It is not a property graph and even graph databases  that use a property graph model will have different storage representations.

Answer (score 0):

Nice exercise, note Redis has many ways of storing data. But I suppose in your case it would just have a key (identifier) something we can always refer back to when retrieving the data.. e.g. BonusId and the rest would be for example json. Again note, there's tons of ways to get data into Redis.

```
SET BonusId '{"Last":"Doe","First":Johnn, "Bonus": 8000}'
```

^ example of how to set key/value through Redis CLI.